# how do i implement a operation between built-in objects and created classes the other way around in python?

Tags: python, class, oop, operator-overloading

Let's say I want to define a class with a `__mul__` method, for example:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,*arg,**kwarg):
        #some code
    def __mul__(self,other):
        #some code
```

If I do `A()*2` it will give me a result. But when I try the other way around (`2*A()`), it doesn't work.
Is there a way to implement this other way around operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `object.__rmul__(self, other)`:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        #some code
    def __mul__(self, other):
        #some code
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self * other
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html